# Spinnaker + ECR access

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, spinnaker, amazon-ecr

I'm having trouble setting up Spinnaker with ECR access.

**Background**: I installed spinnaker using helm on an EKS cluster and I've confirmed that the cluster has the necessary ECR permissions (by manually running ECR commands from within the clouddriver pod).  I am following the instructions here to get Spinnaker+ECR set up: https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/install/providers/docker-registry/

**Issue**: When I run:

```
hal config provider docker-registry account add my-ecr-registry \
--address $ADDRESS \
--username AWS \
--password-command "aws --region us-west-2 ecr get-authorization-token --output text --query 'authorizationData[].authorizationToken' | base64 -d | sed 's/^AWS://'"
```

I get the following output:

```
+ Get current deployment
  Success
- Add the some-ecr-registry account
  Failure
Problems in default.provider.dockerRegistry.some-ecr-registry:
- WARNING Resolved Password was empty, missing dependencies for
  running password command?
- WARNING You have a supplied a username but no password.
! ERROR Unable to fetch tags from the docker repository: code, 400
  Bad Request
? Can the provided user access this repository?
- WARNING None of your supplied repositories contain any tags.
  Spinnaker will not be able to deploy any docker images.
? Push some images to your registry.
Problems in halconfig:
- WARNING There is a newer version of Halyard available (1.28.0),
  please update when possible
? Run 'sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install
  spinnaker-halyard -y' to upgrade
- Failed to add account some-ecr-registry for provider
  dockerRegistry.
```

- I have confirmed that the aws-cli is installed on the clouddriver pod.  And I've confirmed that I can the password-command directly from the clouddriver pod and it successfully returns a token.
- I've also confirmed that if I manually generate an ECR token and `run hal config provider docker-registry account add my-ecr-registry --address $ADDRESS --username AWS  --password-command "echo $MANUALLY_GENERATED_TOKEN"` everything works fine.  So there is something specific to the password-command that is going wrong and I'm not sure how to debug this.
- One other odd behavior: if I simplify the password command to be: `hal config provider docker-registry account add some-ecr-registry --address $ADDRESS --username AWS --repositories code --password-command "aws --region us-west-2 ecr get-authorization-token"` , I get an addt'l piece of output that says `"- WARNING Password command returned non 0 return code stderr/stdout was:bash: aws: command not found"`.  This output only appears for this simplified command.

Any advice on how to debug this would be much appreciated.

Comment: If this command is working `aws --region us-west-2 ecr get-authorization-token --output text --query 'authorizationData[].authorizationToken' | base64 -d | sed 's/^AWS://` I would simply send it to a variable `PASSWORD="aws --region us-west-2 ecr get-authorization-token --output text --query 'authorizationData[].authorizationToken' | base64 -d | sed 's/^AWS://"` and use as in `run hal config provider docker-registry account add my-ecr-registry --address $ADDRESS --username AWS  --password-command "echo $PASSWORD"`.

Answer (score 1):

If like me your ECR registry is in another account, then you have to forcibly assume the role  for the target account where your registry resides

`` passwordCommand: read -r AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY AWS_SESSION_TOKEN <<< `aws sts assume-role  --role-arn arn:aws:iam::<AWS_ACCOUNT>:role/<SPINNAKER ROLE_NAME> --query "[Credentials.AccessKeyId, Credentials.SecretAccessKey, Credentials.SessionToken]"  --output text --role-session-name spinnakerManaged-w2`; export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY AWS_SESSION_TOKEN; aws ecr get-authorization-token --region us-west-2  --output text --query 'authorizationData[].authorizationToken' --registry-ids <AWS_ACCOUNT> | base64 -d | sed 's/^AWS://' ``

Credits to https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/issues/5374#issuecomment-607468678

Answer (score 0):

I also installed Spinnaker on AKS and all i did was by using an AWS Managing User with the correct AWS IAM policy to ECR:* i have access to the ECR repositories directly.
I dont think that `hal` being java based will execute the Bash command in `--password-command`

- set the [AWS ECS provider](https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/install/providers/aws/aws-ecs/) in your spinnaker deployment
- Use the Following AWS IAM policy (SpinnakerManagingPolicy) to be attached to the AWS MAnaging User to give access to ECR. Please replace the AWS Accounts based on your need.

> ```
> {
>     "Version": "2012-10-17",
>     "Statement": [
>         {
>             "Effect": "Allow",
>             "Action": [
>                 "ec2:*",
>                 "cloudformation:*",
>                 "ecr:*"                
>             ],
>             "Resource": [
>                 "*"
>             ]
>         },
>         {
>             "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
>             "Resource": [
>                 "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/SpinnakerManagedRoleAccount1",
>                 "arn:aws:iam::101121314157:role/SpinnakerManagedRoleAccount2",
>                 "arn:aws:iam::202122232425:role/SpinnakerManagedRoleAccount3"
>             ],
>             "Effect": "Allow"
>         }
>     ]
> }
> ```